# What's the person who sits in the counter and makes payments in a restaurant called?

Tags: single-word-requests

A `clerk` is a receptionist in a hotel. What is a person who specifically is responsible of receiving payments in a restaurant called? I'm looking for something better than `Salesclerk`.

Comment: I've worked in two situations: when I took money from the table and worked at the cashier, I was a waiter.  When I took money at the bar, I was a  bartender.  Fast food restaurants may have a dedicated cashier, but give it a fun individual name.

Comment: The title and the body of your question don't match - the person at the till doesn't usually make payments; they receive them. It's the *customer* who sits at the counter (or table) and *pays* for their meal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [cashier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cashier) would be one option. In more up-market establishments it may well be the maître d'hôtel (often abbreviated to [maître d'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maitre_d%27hotel)) who would handle these payments, though not necessarily while sitting at a counter.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a ***cashier***.

ODO:

> **[cashier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cashier)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> A person handling payments and receipts in a shop, bank, or business.
>
> ‘The cashier took the check and handed her a receipt.’